# Can't delete file I own on Linux

Tags: linux, unix, debian

This is on a Debian box:

```
[ampeg]$ ls -la
total 36
dr-xr-xr-x 3 matt pg104272  4096 2011-01-27 10:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 matt pg104272  4096 2012-01-04 12:05 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 matt pg104272 11290 2012-01-02 06:41 default.settings.php
drwxrwxrwx 2 matt pg104272  4096 2012-01-04 11:56 files
-rwxrwxrwx 1 matt pg104272 10389 2011-01-27 10:34 settings.php
[ampeg]$ rm settings.php
rm: cannot remove `settings.php': Permission denied
```

I'm logged on as that `matt` user.

How is it possible that I can't delete that file?

Comment: sudo rm settings.php

Comment: You can try using **lsattr** on that file.

Comment: i dont have root access on that machine

Comment: [ampeg]$ lsattr settings.php
------------------- settings.php

Comment: @clamp: wooh, then i dunno.. read-only filesystem?

Comment: no, other files i can delete normally.

Comment: @clamp: **strace rm -f settings.php**?

Comment: well that outputs a lot of stuff, anything specific i should look out for?

Comment: "lsattr -l" worked for me.  Somehow the file I was trying to delete had the immutable attribute set.  Thanks @clamp!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have no write access on that directory.

```
dr-xr-xr-x 3 matt pg104272  4096 2011-01-27 10:37 .
```

You can't delete a file within a directory you don't have  write access to. Moreover, quoting the [Ubuntu Community manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions), "write access for a directory allows deleting of files in the directory even if the user does not have write permissions for the file".

Obtain write privileges, then you're good to go.

Comment: damn, **slhck** is absolutely correct, lol..